# How do I troubleshoot "InternalServerError" returned by ARM deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

Trying to deploy custom module to Azure Automation account and getting error during deployment.
So there are 2 issues:
1. Deployment instead of failing ending up indefinetely stack with `InternalServerError`
2. Failure itself is non-descriptive and impossible to troubleshoot

Error

```
{
  "code": "InternalServerError",
  "message": "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"
}
```

Template

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "Automation Account Name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
            "location": "southcentralus",
            "name": "[parameters('Automation Account Name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Basic"
                }
            },
            "tags": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "cdscdockerswarm",
                    "type": "modules",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
                    "properties": {
                        "contentLink": {
                            "uri": "https://github.com/artisticcheese/dockerswarmarm/raw/master/modules/cdscdockerswarm.zip"
                        }
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('Automation Account Name'))]"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: I also could reproduce it on my side with you mentioned code. Have you reference to this [blog](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/11/26/deploy-custom-azure-automation-integration-modules-using-arm-templates/). If it still no useful, I suggest that you could use the [create or update modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/module/createorupdate) API with powershell.

Comment: Case opened with Microsoft. Issue reproduced by Microsoft and sent to responsible team for further input.

Comment: If any update you could comment here or add an answer.

Comment: Got note from Microsoft that it's a bug and will be fixed on 4/13/2018

Comment: Thanks for your information.